# How can I prevent my old iPhone from getting Facebook messages?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have an iPhone 5 and now my husband has my old iPhone 4S. For some reason everytime I have a message on Facebook, he's also getting them on his phone under the "Facebook Messenger". How can I fix this, so he doesn't get them?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your account is still linked to your old phone.

Make sure you are signed out of Facebook on that phone. If this doesn't work, try deleting and reinstalling the app. (This should clear any settings associated with the app.)

Answer (score 1):

Before setting him up on your used phone, you should reset the iPhone (Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings), and restore it as a new phone.